# Postfix e-mail forwarding

Tags: linux, wordpress, email, dns

I've a cloud server at DigitalOcean and a domain from Namecheap. I transferred the domain to DigitalOcean. What I want is to setup an e-mail forwarding, e.g.

E-mails sent to contact@mydomain.com should be forwarded to adam@gmail.com

So I did what you usually do when you want something done, use google and look for guides/tutorials and I found this: http://www.andreagrandi.it/2014/08/31/getting-started-with-digital-ocean-vps-configuring-dns-and-postfix-for-email-forwarding/

I followed it and added the DNS stuff (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaUBb.png). DigitalOcean also had a "Add GMAIL MX records" button so I clicked that, these are marked with red rectangulares in the image.

I installed postfix, edited the main.cf, I copied andreagrandi's main.cf and replaced his domain with mine. This is how my main.cf looks like but I've just used mydomain here to be 'anonymous'.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

myhostname = mydomain.com
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_una
***uth_destination <- I've removed this.***
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

One thing I'd to remove from main.cf was

uth_destination, it gave me an error message when it was in there.

```
postmap: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 32: missing '=' after attribute name: "uth_destination"
```

I've tried to get some information about this command but I've not found anything, it's like a big desert at postfix.org for me. If I add "=" it will give me a new error and tell me it has no parameter.

```
 /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: uth_destination=
```

So I thought the best would be to just remove it.

Let's move on. Create a virtual file and edit it.

```
nano /etc/postfix/virtual
```

In my file called virtual I've the following

```
admin@mydomain.com adam@gmail.com
contact@mydomain.com adam@gmail.com
adam@mydomain.com adam@gmail.com
```

I saved it and I can see it by using the l command.

```
cd /etc/postfix
l
dynamicmaps.cf  main.cf  master.cf  postfix-files  postfix-script*  post-install*  sasl/  virtual  virtual.db
```

Then I just run the two commands

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
sudo /etc/init.d/postfix reload
```

and I get an [ OK ] response.

When I try to send an e-mail to adam@mydomain.com I just receive

> postmaster@mail.hotmail.com (postmaster@mail.hotmail.com)
>   Delivery Status Notification (Failure)‏

The e-mail is never delivered to my Gmail address and now my contact-forms at my wordpress-site doesn't work either. I am a beginner in Linux.

Edit: I may have something here..

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep 25

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1071/master
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1071/master
```

The port 25 marked in RED. Could it be because it's closed/blocked? I search for it on google and seems like DigitalOcean blocks port 25 for new users? Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1071/master
```

means the process is LISTENing on the port, you want this.

Please add output of `postconf -n` and `grep contact /var/log/mail.log`

Take the ID from that output, which will look something like this:

```
Jul 29 21:37:47 ent01 postfix/pickup[6214]: A34E3F40485: uid=0 from=<root>
Jul 29 21:37:47 ent01 postfix/cleanup[6538]: A34E3F40485: message-id=<20150730023747.A34E3F40485@ent01>
Jul 29 21:37:47 ent01 postfix/qmgr[1116]: A34E3F40485: from=<root@ent01>, size=263, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 29 21:37:47 ent01 postfix/local[6540]: A34E3F40485: to=<root@ent01>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.22, delays=0.16/0.01/0/0.06, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Jul 29 21:37:47 ent01 postfix/qmgr[1116]: A34E3F40485: removed
```

and do:

```
grep A34E3F40485 /var/log/mail.log
```

This will likely point you in the right direction as postfix logging is very very useful when troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress, there is a plugin that makes this email forwarding. You don't need to install Postfix just for this task. 
The plugin is called Mailshogun and this is exactly what it does. Forward info@mydomain to myname@gmail.com. 
Then you can use the Send From function to send back emails with mydomain.com.